# How to specify an end time for a Sound

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

With the Sound.play function, you can specify a start time in milliseconds as one of the arguments, as well as the number of times to loop the sound. Am I missing something, or is there not a way to specify an end time? For example, if I want the loop milliseconds 5-105 of a 4 second sound, is there a way to specify it to start the next loop at 105 milliseconds?

If I'm not missing something, is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sound` class doesn't allow you to perform that operation, the best way to do this is by using a Timer:

```
var musicTimer:Timer = new Timer(100, 5); // Loop total time(ms), N Loops (+1)
musicTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, musicTimer_tick);
musicTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, musicTimer_complete);
musicTimer.start();

private function musicTimer_complete(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // Last loop stop all sounds
    channel.stop();
}

private function musicTimer_tick(e:TimerEvent):void 
{
    // At each loop, stop and (re)start the sound
    channel.stop();
    channel = sound.play(5); // 5 is the loop start time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another `Sound` object tailored for your desired looping settings. You then call `Sound:extract()` against your source sound, extracting the exact values that your sound needs to loop, then on your target sound you call `loadPCMFromByteArray()` and then loop that sound.

```
function loopASound(sound:Sound,startTime:uint,endTime:uint,loops:int):SoundChannel {
    var ba:ByteArray=new ByteArray();
    var startPos:uint=Math.floor(startTime*44.1);
    var endPos:uint=Math.floor(endTime*44.1); 
    // sound rate is always 44100, and positions are expected in milliseconds,
    // as with all the functions of Sound class
    sound.extract(ba,endPos-startPos,startPos); // get raw data
    var ripped:Sound=new Sound();
    ba.position=0;
    ripped.loadPCMFromByteArray(ba,endPos-startPos); // format, stereo and sample rate at defaults
    return ripped.play(0,loops);
}
```

Warning: the code is untested and produced only by reading the manuals. Also you might want to store the `ripped` sound somewhere too, so you won't do the ripping all the time if you're planning to loop the same segment more than several times.